# Proof of Darboux's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I tried to prove Darboux's theorem. It is the following theorem:

Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function and let $f'(a) < \alpha < f'(b)$. Then there exists $c \in [a,b]$ with $f'(c) = \alpha$.

Please could somebody check my proof?

Define $g(x) = f(x) - \alpha x$. Then $g$ is continuous and because $[a,b]$ is compact $g$ attains its minimum on $[a,b]$. Let $x_m \in [a,b]$ be such that $g(x_m) \le g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. If $x_m \in (a,b)$ then $g'(x_m) = 0 = f'(x_m) - \alpha$ which shows the claim.

If $x_m = a$ then $g'(x_m) = g'(a) < 0$. Because $g$ is continuous and $g'(a) < 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $x \in (a,a+\delta)$ then $g(x) < g(a) = g(x_m)$. But this is a contradiction because $x_m$ is the minimum. If $x_m = b$ then again there is $\delta>0$ such that if $x \in (b-\delta, b)$ then $g(x)<g(b)=g(x_m)$ because  $g'(b) > 0$. Again this is a contradiction. It follows that the minimum is attained in the interior $(a,b)$.

Comment: The case $x_m=a$ (as well as $x_m=b$) does not follow "Because $g$ is continuous ...", but because $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$ exists and is negative.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But if $g$ is not coninuous then it could be that there are no $x$ with $g(x) < g(x_m)$ (like e.g. if $g(x) = 1$ everywhere except $g(x_m) = 0$? Only because of continuity of $g$ we can find $\delta$ so that all $x$ that are $\delta$ close to $x_m$ have the property $g(x) < g(x_m)$.

Comment: @blue: In your example function, how would you define $g'(x_m)$?

Comment: @fixedp I don't understand your comment. $g$ and $x_m$ are defined in the question and so is $x_m$?

Comment: @blue I was referring to the function $g(x)$ in your comment where $g(x_m)=1$ and $g(x)=1$ otherwise. How would you define $g'(x_m)$ for this function?

Comment: @fixedp It's not continuous at $x_m$ so $g'(x_m)$ can't exist. It is a bad example.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I am sorry, I still don't understand why I can't use continuity to argue.

Comment: @Nirav You are assuming $\alpha = 0$?

Comment: Ok, we went a bit off tangent here. The point is that you do not need continuity, just the fact that the limit given by Hagen von Eitzen exists and is negative.

Comment: Basically, I think your proof is sound. The criticism comes from stating that the function _f_ is differentiable at the endpoint of the interval - since you are working at the endpoint, you need to define the derivative there using a one-sided limit, and so, technically, by some definitions of the derivative, one should not say the derivative exists at the endpoints. If you said the function was differentiable on an open interval containing $[a,b]$ that would eliminate that criticism. But basically, your proof is sound.

Comment: @blue I think the point of Hagen's comment is just to say that the continuity of $g$ is not needed in the argument. The only think you use is that the right-derivative at $a$ exists and is negative. So it is not necessary to write "because $g$ is continuous"'.

Comment: @Etienne Thank you for your comment. It is not necessary but it is correct... I understand it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If $x_m=a$ then $g′(x_m)=g′(a)<0$. Because $g$ is continuous and $g′(a)<0$ there exists $δ>0$ such that if $x∈(a,a+δ)$ then $g(x)<g(a)=g(x_m)$.

You do not *need* continuity of $g$ here. In fact, this step step is valid even if $g$ is differentiable in $a$ but not continuous anywhere (except at $a$ where it must be continuous because it is differentiable). It is immediate from $g'(a)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}<0$ that for at least some $h>0$ we have $\left|\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}-g'(a)\right|<\frac12|g'(a)|$ and hence $\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}<0$ and finally $g(a+h)<g(a)$, contradicting the minimum at $a$.

> But this is a contradiction because $x_m$ is the minimum. If $x_m=b$ then again there is $δ>0$ such that if $x∈(b−δ,b)$ then $g(x)<g(b)=g(x_m)$ because $g′(b)>0$. Again this is a contradiction. It follows that the minimum is attained in the interior $(a,b)$.

(Exactly, and in that case we can conclude $g'(x_m)=0$, hence $f'(x_m)=\alpha$ ...)

So, basically, your proof is valid. However, since you added the unnecessary (for that single step)  condition that $g$ is continuous I was afraid that you were not completely sure what you really used there.

Comment: Maybe I should write ''Because $g$ is continuous at $a$'' in my proof. The argument with the limit and $h$ in your answer is very similar to using the continuity of $g$ at $a$.