# Proof related to Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove: Let f be differentiable on $[a,b]$.If $f'(a)>0$ and $f'(b) <0$, then exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$ (Do not assume that $f'$ is continuous).

My attempt: If $f(a) = f(b)$, then by Rolle's Theorem, it's done. Assume $f(a) \neq f(b)$, say $f(a) < f(b)$. I want to prove that $\exists x_0 \in (a,b)$ s.t. $f(x_0)=f(b)$, so using Rolle's Theorem again I can get the answer. But I cannot find how to prove it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: This is a particular case of Darboux's Theorem. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771201/proof-of-darbouxs-theorem) is a related question.

Comment: Hint: show that the maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is not at an endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ hence it has a $\max$.
Let $x_0$ be any point at which $f$ attains the $\max$ and note that
because of the assumptions, $x_0 \in (a,b)$.

We must have $f'(x_0) = 0$.